# How to omit one or more column from updating when Entity Framework AddOrUpdate executes?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework `AddOrUpdate` method like this:

```
customerDbSet.AddOrUpdate(r => new { r.CustomerNumber, r.ReportNumber }, items);
```

This method is looking `CustomerNumber` and `ReportNumber` to determine whether insert or update those `items`. But, in some cases, I need to omit one more column to be updated. Is there any way to do this?

Like :

```cs
customerDbSet.AddOrUpdate(r => new { r.CustomerNumber, r.ReportNumber }, items, c => new { c.Reviewed } /* do not update `Reviewed` column.*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set individual properties as unmodified to prevent the update from changing them, eg before SaveChanges():

```
foreach (var e in db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is Customer))
{
    e.Property(nameof(Customer.Reviewed)).IsModified = false;
}
```

Comment: Does this also work correctly for items will insert?